# Wanting to insert for the first time in database and getting an error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

So this is my code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = null;
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"; 
//ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
//FileInputStream fis;

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"root","123");
psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Table1 (name, desc, r,g,b," +
    "varR,varG,varB,skewnessR,skewnessG,skewnessB)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
final String text2 = setName.getText();
final String text3=setDesc.getText();
psmnt.setString(1,text2);
psmnt.setString(2,text3);
psmnt.setString(3,stringMeanR);
psmnt.setString(4,stringMeanG);
psmnt.setString(5,stringMeanB);
psmnt.setString(6,stringVarianceR);
psmnt.setString(7,stringVarianceG);
psmnt.setString(8,stringVarianceB);
psmnt.setString(9,stringSkewnessR);
psmnt.setString(10,stringSkewnessG);
psmnt.setString(11,stringSkewnessB);

//fis = new FileInputStream(f);

//psmnt.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream)fis, (int)(f.length()));
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
psmnt.close();
connection.close();
if(s>0) {
    System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Unsucessfull to upload image.");
}
```

The problem is that i get the following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, r,g,b,varR,varG,varB,skewnessR,skewnessG,skewnessB)values('','','105.59 , ' at line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved SQL keyword (used in `order by foo desc`). Change the name of the column you named "desc" (or escape it using backticks, but I would change the name to make it easier)

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a reserved keyword in SQL for describing an SQL table. As a result, if your column name is 'description' then it should be 'description'; not 'desc' as `desc` is reserved in MySQL for describing the table itself or showing the SQL code for the creation of the table.